# Как разбить картинку на секции в CSS?

Tags: html, css

Собственно нужно сверстать вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это вообще реализуемо средствами CSS?

Comment: такое еще =) http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/KgPxpy?editors=1100

Answer (score 5):

Самое простое, с помощью таблицы.

```css
table {
  background: url(https://snap-photos.s3.amazonaws.com/img-thumbs/280h/2FQ69FRGV6.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  width: 420px;
  height: 280px;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  border: 4px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Никогда не видел такого применения таблицам, вы сделали меня чуть-чуть умнее)

Comment: Но ты же закрываешь часть изображения, а не разрезаешь его...

Comment: @Qwertiy, странно, что некропостингом занимаешься. А в чем принципиальная разница, если нужен визуальный эффект? Естественно, если нужно именно разрезать картинку на секции (например, для сохранения куда-то еще), реализация будет другой. Можно было бы конечно и с помощью JS картинку распределить по отдельным блокам, вычислив смещения. Или именно разрезать картинку по координатам на бэкенде.

Answer (score 4):

Пример 1

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pict-container{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.pict{
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background: #ccc url(http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/5731016652bcd063018c1e12-480/ferrari-488gtb-1.jpg) no-repeat center top;;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.pict:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: #fff;
}
.pict > span{
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 25%;
   width: 10px;   
   height: 100%;   
   margin-left: -5px;
   background: #fff;   
}
.pict > span:nth-of-type(2){left: 50%;}
.pict > span:nth-of-type(3){left: 75%;}
```

```html
<div class="pict-container">
  <div class="pict">  
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Пример 2

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.pict-container{
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 15px auto;
}
.pict{
  padding-bottom: 50%; 
  position: relative;
}
.pict > img{
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.pict:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}
.pict > span{
   position: absolute; top: 0; left: 25%;
   width: 10px;   
   height: 100%;   
   margin-left: -5px;
   background: #fff;   
}
.pict > span:nth-of-type(2){left: 50%;}
.pict > span:nth-of-type(3){left: 75%;}
```

```html
<div class="pict-container">
  <div class="pict">  
      <img src="http://static1.businessinsider.com/image/5731016652bcd063018c1e12-480/ferrari-488gtb-1.jpg" alt="">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Этот вариант самый оптимальный в сравнении с указанными выше, так как здесь картинка не является бэккграундом и к ней можно прописать альт и тайтл. Гениально реализовано!

Comment: И тут тоже изображение не разрезается, а накрывается полосками.

Comment: Так и не понял, почему автор не хочет разрезать изображение на несколько и задать их бэкграундами к нескольким блокам. На счёт алтов не согласен. Если вы таким образом переделываете изображение, значит оно является скорее визуальной составляющей, нежели контентом. А значит установка её бэкграундом вполне приемлима.

Comment: Забудьте про alt вообще! 99% не знают для чего оно вообще нужно